# 500 server error on uploading files more that specific size on php when php.ini conf is correct

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, dropzone.js

I have this PHP configuration:

```
ini_get('max_execution_time') = 3000
ini_get('memory_limit') = 256
ini_get('post_max_size') = 200M
ini_get('upload_max_filesize') = 200M
```

On this environment:

```
CentOS 7 server
CentOS Web Panel
Apache web server 2.4
PHP 7.2 
Laravel framework 7.0
```

And when I try to upload files more than 1MB I get a 500 internal server error!

This is the error in network tab:

[image]

Other info about request:

[image]

I tried everything that I had in mind like setting ini in controller changing the sending file method from ajax to simple form, etc... but no luck!

I also restarted the httpd service even restarted the server so maybe the changes make affect but nothing changes

**Edit:**
I also see this error in apache logs:

```
Handler for (null) returned invalid result code 70007
```

Comment: ___Small Point___ 
`post_max_size` shoudl be larger than `upload_max_filesize` to allow for field data as well as files. But its probably not the reason for your issue

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly I will change that too see maybe made a change :))

Comment: I had the same issue long time ago but sorry I cant remember what the reason was. Did you set the max_file_size in the HTML from also to more then 1MB?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff I'm using dropzone a js lib for uploading files and in the settings I sat maxfilesize is it enaught?

Comment: the only thing you can do is insert a debug output and die() at the beginning of the php script and move it step bxy step forward to the and as long as the debug output no longer beiing written. Then you know which line in the PHP script causes the 500

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff the error happens at the middle of uploading it's not related to the codes I guess

Comment: ini_get('memory_limit') = 256 (maybe that is just a typo, shouldn't it be 256M?

Comment: @bumperbox I know, It's just sharing information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of researches and tries I found the problem and in doesn't make sense at all!

As in this link said:
[7007 apache error](http://forum.centos-webpanel.com/index.php?topic=6758.msg25890#msg25890)

I had to just disable this line:

```
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules / mod_reqtimeout.so
```

From Apache httpd.conf file

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps anybody else, I had specifically set a directive in my `httpd.conf` which limited the size of uploads to the server:

```
LimitRequestBody nnn...nnn
```

(`nnn...nnn` being in bytes)